# How to monitor websocket frames in firefox

Tags: firefox, websocket

I know there was an extension called 'websocket-monitor', but it's no longer available.

It seems that nobody can view websocket frames by firefox.

Answer (score 28):

That is currently not possible with the latest version of Firefox, but it has been logged and there is an open thread in Bugzilla regarding it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=885508).

**Update September 2019**: According to [this](https://twitter.com/FirefoxDevTools/status/1175081233048465409) tweet from Mozilla, the WebSocket inspection is now working natively on the Firefox Developer edition.

**Update October 2019**: According to [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/10/firefoxs-new-websocket-inspector/) extensive blog post from Mozilla, the feature will be released in Firefox 71. Until that, you can use Firefox Developer edition.

**Update December 2019**: Firefox 71 got released today and includes WebSocket inspection according to the [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/71.0/releasenotes/).

You can download the Firefox Developer edition from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/).

**Update October 2020**: Sometime between Firefox 71 and Firefox 79 the "Messages" tab was removed and instead the WebSocket messages inspection was moved to the standard "Response" tab.

Comment: In the meantime, use Chrome for debugging websocket.

Comment: Am I doing it wrong? I have Firefox 79 (August 2020) and I see the websocket connection status 101 under Network, but when I click it, there is no "Messages" panel to get the message detail :(  Tested with https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. It works fine on Chrome but I wanted to use it on Firefox.

Comment: When you click on the connection there is a "Response" tab which logs all messages sent and received, prepended with green and red arrows respectively.

Answer (score 10):

It's now possible to view/sniff WebSocket messages/frames/packets with the [Nightly build of Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/#nightly).
 I have never used the Firefox Nightly build before, but it seems to be working okay.

Here's a screenshot: [image: Firefox Nightly build WebSocket messages]

Comment: I am on 68.0.1 (64-bit), but don't see that "messages" tab but the others I see.

Comment: The nightly build of Firefox is a different version of Firefox. Make sure you download the nightly build that I linked to. I am using the Mac version (70.0a1 (2019-08-07) (64-bit)) of the nightly build.

Answer (score 7):

[WebSocket Sniffer](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/websocketsniff) seems to work with Firefox 63.

Comment: It replaces the native WebSocket object with a custom object.

Comment: You have to code with a different `Websocket`, which means differences with normal `WebSocket`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firefox developer edition: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer

Then you open *Developer tools -> Network -> Filter by Websocket -> Messages*

[image]