# Inspect Websocket Frames with Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, websocket, firefox-addon

I want to inspect Websocket frames in Firefox Quantum. I haven't found an option to inspect the frames (as it's possible with Chrome Developer). Is it not possible with Firefox Quantum? Really?

What have I missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor websocket frames in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697329/how-to-monitor-websocket-frames-in-firefox)

Comment: Ditto on the possible duplicate. I posted an answer here, but someone deleted it as duplicate answer. In short, it's now possible with the Firefox Nightly build. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697329/how-to-monitor-websocket-frames-in-firefox/57397586#57397586

Comment: It's now available!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible in Firefox Quantum. There is a bug,  [bug 885508](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=885508), which wants to allow developers to inspect websocket connections, but it has not been resolved, so you can't do it in Firefox. However, progress has been made. There was a [add-on (now removed)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/websocket-monitor/), but it doesn't work with Quantum. Some people use [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/websocketsniff/), but it replaces native WebSockets with a custom object.

---

**Update:** It is now possible in Firefox 71.0! [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/Inspecting_web_sockets)

> DevTools’ Network panel can now inspect WebSocket messages and automatically formats a variety of framework formats.

To get to it:

1. Open the developer view. (Ctrl+Shift+I)
2. Go to the network tab.[image: The network tab.]
3. Press the WS tab.[image: The WS tab.]
4. (optional) Press a message to view info about it.

[image]