# How does a webapp like web.whatsapp posts an input without sending requests

Tags: server, request, communication

In Web.Whatsapp you can chat with your mobile phone contacts using wifi, even when your phone is not online. However when I first looked in to how a webapp like whatsapp 'posts' your send message (or receive incoming) I did not notice any form of outgoing requests, posts / get requests etc on my chrome / firefox developer tool.

The developer in me would like to know how whatsapp sends my messages to the server without me seeing that in the network area. If whatsapp interacts to the server on a different way i would love to know whether that part is visible just like in 'network'.

other site where I can not see network interaction is for example:
youtube when posting an comment or giving a like

[image: Empty Network field]

Comment: Have you looked at websocket (WS) traffic? I can see the WS button on your network panel, but it is not selected. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50697329/773113

Comment: No websockets can be found when selecting WS. However when selecting XHR I do find requests on Youtube. Web.whatsapp is still a mystery for me.